# What is tithe and why did Abraham give 10%? (Gen. 14:20)

Tags: genesis, abraham, melchizedek, tithes

What is tithe?

Why did Abraham give 10% (Genesis 14) and not 20% or 5%?

Is there any inner meaning for tithe in ancient Hebrew texts?

Comment: Welcome Raju! This is a good question but please be aware that the norm on this site is to include a specific biblical text. I've taken the liberty of editing your question accordingly. Please take a look at the Tour and the Help paged (links at the bottom-left of the page) when you have a chance.

Answer (score 2):

A tithe was a custom already present in Mesopotamia and Syria-Palestine before Abraham's time.  It was usually connected with a royally-established shrine or center of worship.  Scholars' best guess as to why one-tenth was a common figure is that people were accustomed to counting on their fingers -- which indicates that we just don't know.
This fits what we know of Abraham and Melchizedek.  "Melchizedek" in Hebrew means "king of righteousness' (or "righteous king"); he is called "king of Salem" which if translated means "king of peace".  We know from the text in Genesis 14 that he was both king and priest, from which we can conclude that his was a royal worship center and thus a tithe would have been appropriate [note: a tithe back then was one-tenth of what a person owned, not of income].
So when Abraham stopped in the Valley of Shaveh with the king of Sodom and Melchizedek appears, Abraham apparently followed the existing custom and offered a tenth of all he had.
Later the tithe was included in instructions given to Moses, e.g. Numbers 18 and Deuteronomy 12.

With regard to the 20% question, that percentage shows up in the story of Joseph where Pharaoh got a fifth of all produce in the land, but this figure has no relationship to the tithe.

Comment: Thanks for an informative answer. It would further profit from references to the sources used.

Comment: I interpret "a tenth of all/everything" as referring only the war plunder, not Abraham's other wealth. See the following verses, the king of Sodom demands to be given Abraham's captives but would allow him to keep the other plunder.

Comment: @grammaplow  Unfortunately my source would be "grad school courses in ancient near eastern literature".   I doubt I even have the course bibliographies any longer.

Answer (score 2):

The answer lies in the religious geo-politics of the story. The tithe was a tribute offered to a senior military or religious partner/protector. In Genesis 14, Abraham was recently still a nomad. He had just settled at Hebron (Gen. 13:18) and Melchizedek was the king of the nearest large city, Salem.

[image]

Abraham's small army had joined with various allies to liberate Lot in a war against Chedorlaomer of Elam. (Gen. 14:1-14) Genesis 14:15 states that the war ended north of Damascus. The text does not mention Salem's role in this conflict but Melchizedek came out to meet Abraham on the latter's way back south to Hebron. There, they formed an alliance, marked by a sacred meal of bread and wine followed by a prayer, in which Melchizedek pronounced the following blessing:

> “Blessed be Abram by God Most High,
> the creator of heaven and earth;  And blessed be God Most High,
> who delivered your foes into your hand.”

Immediately after this Abraham offered "a tenth of everything" to Melchizedek, apparently meaning both captives and material plunder, including livestock. This tithe was a tribute offered by Abraham to Melchizedek in token of Salem's position as the dominant local city, but it also had a spiritual dimension. After receiving Melchizedek's blessing, Abraham immediately rejected a share of the plunder offered by the king of Sodom. Melchizedek and Abraham shared a belief in God, whether by the name El Elyon (God Most High), El Shaddai (God of Power) or the Lord (YHWH). Abraham rejected Sodom's offer because "I have sworn to *the Lord, God Most High*." This is the first time - seemingly the only time - these two names for God are used as one title.

Why specifically a tithe? Apparently this was a [common practice](https://www.encyclopedia.com/environment/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/tithes):

> In the ancient Near East lie the origins of a sacral offering or
> payment of a tenth part of stated goods or property to the deity.
> Often given to the king or to the royal temple, the "tenth" was
> usually approximate, not exact. The practice is known from
> Mesopotamia, Syria-Palestine, Greece, and as far to the west as the
> Phoenician city of Carthage.

**Conclusion**: The tithe was a customary tribute offered to a political ally or protector.  Melchizedek was the king of the dominant city of the nearby area. Thus it was normal that Abraham would offer him a tithe of any plunder after a battle, especially if Salem's forces were helpful. The text does not tell us if this tribute was offered only one time or on a regular basis. In addition, because the two leaders' religions were compatible, Abraham was willing to offer his tithe to Melchizedek as the priest of El Elyon, while rejecting an offer of tribute from the king of Sodom.

Comment: @ Dan Fefferman - Informative, as always! But it would have been great if the Encyclopedia article gave the Ancient countries, literature references:  Manuscripts, engravings, monuments, priestly codes, etc. discovered by archaeology.

Comment: @raygrant the sources are not plentiful, especially prior to Abraham's time. Here are two articles: https://bycommonconsent.com/2006/11/01/tithing-and-the-poor/  https://archive.org/stream/thesacredtenthor01lansuoft/thesacredtenthor01lansuoft_djvu.txt

Comment: @Good! I downloaded "The Sacred Tenth". Peace!

Answer (score 1):

"Tithe" is simply an old-English word meaning one tenth.

Why 10% and not 5% or 20%??

That is what God specified in numerous places such as Lev 27:30, 31, Num 18:24, 26, 28, Deut 12:6, 17, 26, 12, 2 Chron 31:12, Neh 10:38, Mal 3:8, 10, etc.

The first recorded people to give tithe were:

- Abraham, Gen 14:20
- Jacob Gen 28:22

Comment: **First Recorded** The word "tithe" meaning "tenth" was used throughout the ancient nations, pre-dating and during the Patriarchal era.   Tithing was especially associated with "spoils of war." Some consider the sacrifices of Cain and Abel to be a tithe of sorts. But as Dottard related, the biblical tithe is first mentioned by name in Genesis. The Mosaic tithe later, was simply a continuation of what nations had been doing for centuries throughout the Mideast. The difference being, offering it all to the right God!

Answer (score 0):

**Sacred Tenth** The practice of tithing (presenting a tenth) was known from time immemorial!  There is historical record of ancient Egyptian, Babylonian, Persian, Greek empires practicing tithing. (See The Sacred Tithe, by Henry Lansdell, London, 1906, for an in depth history up to the time of the British 20th century...or The Law of the Tithe, by Arthur Babbs, N.Y. 1912)

The tithes was exacted on agricultural crops, and on spoils of war in gratitude of victory to the gods. It was in this cultural milieu that Abraham appears and gives tithes to the ruler/priest of Jerusalem. Jacob later, would also fall in line with this vow/tithe practice of ancient times. (Genesis 14, 28)

**The word** The word for tithe in the ancient cuneiform and papyrus is their word for "tenth." The priest at the gate who accepted the tithes was named accordingly: the "tenth" man, or "tenth" gatherer. Note that sometimes the agricultural tithe of food and animals was sometimes substituted with money (redeemed by money) for convenience.

It was not out of the ordinary then, for Moses to work out a tithing system under the Jewish Law.  It had been part of the Egyptian tradition. Moses laid out three tithes for the people: Levitical tithe, Festival tithe, Poverty tithe.  And this was further  enhanced under the Pharisees at the time of Christ, often becoming burdensome to the common people because new regulations were continually being added. They, Jesus complained, tithes on herbs of the smallest sort, but neglected the weightier matters of the Law: social justice.

**Inner Meaning** There is no "inner meaning" in tithe giving. It was very practical. The priesthoods in the various empires were supported by them. The temples were maintained by them. But the people (and generals) gave willingly to show gratitude to their gods (God) for bountiful harvests, or victory at war.

**Universal Practice** That the giving of the tithe was a universal practice throughout the Mideast is seen by some historians as proof of *common descent* of the human race. (All descending from a Noah figure.) This comports with the historical narrative of the Bible (Pentateuch, Torah). Why the "tenth" number was used, and not another, is left up to more research, or simply to say that God revealed it to Adam from the beginning.